# RESTFul and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, rest

Is there a tool that can create RESTFul java services from classes generated with hibernate tool?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data - REST may be useful.

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-rest/wiki/JPA-Repository-REST-Exporter

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JBoss' RESTEasy framework](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy/)

Answer (score 0):

[Tapestry 5](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/) has great Hibernate integration and uses REST-style URLs.

Answer (score 0):

this is very useful
http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernatepojoge/files/hibernatepojoge/hbnpojogen/

it creates entity ,and services ,
you can try it,very easy